# Set a marker icon in Google Maps API

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps-markers, drawable, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Xamarin and am using the SimpleMapDemo and I have a question about setting a MarkerOptions object to have a different icon.

Here is my current code:

```
marker1.Icon(SetFeatureDrawable('Icon.png'));
```

This above code is not working.

May I please have some help to set the icon to be the icon that is in the Drawable folder that has the name of 'Icon.png'?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
marker1.Icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.monkey));
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Non-invocable member 'Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MarkerOptions.Icon' cannot be used like a method
```

Here is my code to try and set the icon:

```
marker1.Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.monkey);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
CS0200: Property or indexer 'Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MarkerOptions.Icon' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only (CS0200)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code instead:

```
marker1.InvokeIcon(SetFeatureDrawable('Icon.png'));
```

In general, Xamarin tries to bind the Java setter/getters to properties. In this case, although `MarkerOption.icon` looks like a property to C# eyes, it is in fact a Java method. In this case the binding has "translated" the property-like Java method to `MarkerOption.InvokeIcon` in an attempt to conform with C# design guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

```
double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;

MarkerOptions mapMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Your title will be here");

mapMarker .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));

mapView.addMarker(mapMarker );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, using this  i can show custom icon from drawable resource as marker in map

```
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting position on the MarkerOptions
    markerOptions.SetPosition(lt);
    markerOptions.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
```

[image: custom map marker in google map]